# Exception java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist, when trying to make a query to Oracle DB

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, oracle11g, weblogic12c

I've been with a mistake for a few weeks now, I wonder if anyone around here can shed some light...
I have a web application, I built it using Spring Boot and it connects to two databases, both **Oracle**.
In my development environment I deploy in the Spring Boot embedded tomcat and everything works fine. The problem occurs when I deploy in Weblogic (Integration environment) which, when trying to login, returns the following exception at trying to execute a **select**:

```
<Dec 27, 2019 1:58:16,335 PM CET> <Warning> <org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper> <BEA-000000> <SQL Error: 30000, SQLState: 42Y07>
<Dec 27, 2019 1:58:16,336 PM CET> <Error> <org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper> <BEA-000000> <Schema 'SA' does not exist>
<Dec 27, 2019 1:58:16,343 PM CET> <Error> <org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter> <BEA-000000> <Forwarding to error page from request [/login_ldap] due to exception [could not prepare statement; SQL [select userentity0_.id as id1_6_, userentity0_.name as name2_6_, userentity0_.operator as operator3_6_, userentity0_.profile as profile4_6_, userentity0_.roles as roles5_6_, userentity0_.theme as theme6_6_, userentity0_.token as token7_6_ from USERS userentity0_ where userentity0_.name=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select userentity0_.id as id1_6_, userentity0_.name as name2_6_, userentity0_.operator as operator3_6_, userentity0_.profile as profile4_6_, userentity0_.roles as roles5_6_, userentity0_.theme as theme6_6_, userentity0_.token as token7_6_ from USERS userentity0_ where userentity0_.name=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:240)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    ....
    ....
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused By: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:181)
    ....
    ....
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    ....
    ....
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused By: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'SA' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.StatementUtil.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    ....
    ....
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
>
```

I have been visiting many forums and they all refer to an error that can occur when using Derby DB, and in fact, in the trace of the exception I can see `org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException` (I can't understand why).
The problem has appeared when I added the second datasource, since the configuration that Spring Boot brought by default was not good for me and, therefore, I had to configure it "by hand".
Maybe, I have some erroneous configuration, but I can't find it.
My **application.properties** is:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP1:PUERTO1/SERVICIO1
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP1:PUERTO1/SERVICIO1
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME1
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD1
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=USERNAME1

spring.remd-datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.remd-datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP2:PUERTO2/SERVICIO2
spring.remd-datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP2:PUERTO2/SERVICIO2
spring.remd-datasource.username=USERNAME2
spring.remd-datasource.password=PASSWORD2
spring.remd-datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.remd-datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=USERNAME2

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.security.access.intercept=debug
logging.level.org.springframework.security=ERROR
logging.level.com.hpe=DEBUG
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.file=./logs/serverApplication.log

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

And the configuration classes that I created for the two datasources:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = { "com.project.repository.clar" }
)
public class ClarDataSourceConfiguration {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create(properties.getClassLoader())
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .driverClassName(properties.determineDriverClassName())
                .url(properties.determineUrl())
                .username(properties.determineUsername())
                .password(properties.determinePassword())
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.project.model.clar").persistenceUnit("clar").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "remdEntityManagerFactory", 
    transactionManagerRef = "remdTransactionManager", 
    basePackages = { "com.project.repository.remd" }
)
public class RemdDataSourceConfiguration {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.remd-datasource")
    @Bean(name = "remdDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create(properties.getClassLoader())
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .driverClassName(properties.determineDriverClassName())
                .url(properties.determineUrl())
                .username(properties.determineUsername())
                .password(properties.determinePassword())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "remdEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean remdEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("remdDataSource") DataSource remdDataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(remdDataSource).packages("com.project.model.remd").persistenceUnit("remd").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "remdTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager remdTransactionManager(@Qualifier("remdEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory remdEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(remdEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Thanks to everyone in advance and regards!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the mistake. 
For a reason that I can't understand, Spring is not charging the properties defined in application.properties file that I'm trying to read from my configuration class (properties.determineDriverClassName(), properties.determineUrl(), etc). Instead, if I hardcode the values all works perfectly.
As a workaround I've defined these properties in another properties file and works fine, but I'll continue investigating why properties from my application.properties aren't being charging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this may not answer your question, but I ran into the same issue (defining multiple datasources) a while back; this is my solution:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
class PersistenceConfig {
  @Bean(name = "oneDS")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom-namespace.datasource.one")
  public DataSource oneDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "mainDS")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom-namespace.datasource.main")
  public DataSource mainDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "twoDS")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom-namespace.datasource.two")
  public DataSource twoDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(mainDataSource());
  }

  // ...other beans using the other datasources
}
```

...and this is how the `application.yml` looks like for those settings:

> Notice there is NO built-in configuration for the data-sources in `application.yml`.

```
custom-namespace:
  datasource:
    one:
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:/@oneDS
    main:
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:/@mainDS
    two:
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:/@twoDS
server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
  port: "${SERVER_PORT:8080}"
  ssl:
    enabled: true
spring:
  application:
    name: "spring-core"
  banner:
    charset: UTF-8
  http:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      enabled: true
      force: true
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: detect
  profiles:
    active: default
---
spring:
  profiles: development
---
spring:
  profiles: production
---
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: false
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: console
  profiles: sandbox
---
spring:
  profiles: test
```

> Since I'm using Spring profiles they must be "activated"; e.g.: `--spring.profiles.active=sandbox`.

Comment: Hi @x80486!! Thanks so much for your response. I've already tried the solution that you propose but when I try to deploy my application in Weblogic I get the error: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.** (although jdbc-url is in my application.properties)

Comment: What Spring Boot version are you using? It looks like `jdbc-url` didn't work for you; I would try with `url` instead...

Comment: I work with Spring Boot 2.0.6, that it has ''Hikary Connection Pool'' built in, the jdbc-ur propery is necessary for Hikary CP (instead jdbc property). Anyway I've found the mistake. For a reason that I can't understand, Spring is not charging the properties defined in application.properties file that I'm trying to read from my configuration class. Instead, if I hardcode the values all works perfectly. As a workaround I've defined these properties in another properties file and works fine, but I'll continue investigating why properties from my application.properties aren't being charging.

Comment: Thanks for your time and support @x80486 and happy new year!